# iteratively looping through every nth element of an array and deleting it?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop, iteration

Hi i want to delete every nth element of an array iteratively. 
For example if I have an array like this

```
$input = array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
```

and say I need to remove every 4th element. 
In the first iteration 5 will be removed, then 1, then 6, then 3 then 2, then 4, then 8

The number 7 will be left in the array, I want to return that !

Thanks for your help

Comment: php has no built in josephus function. It's easy enough to write it yourself.

Comment: In a zero-based array, 5 is at the 4th *index,* but it is still the 5th element in the array. Anyway, assuming that's what you meant, can you explain how you arrive at "1" after that?

Comment: first we remove 5, then we go back in the circle. (4th element from 5 in the above array is 1)

Comment: @twentylemon  Could you help me if you can ?  THanks